# When does $\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))$ equal $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$? What are the exceptions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

(This question is related to this [earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131818).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  The greatest common divisor of the integers $a$ and $b$ is denoted by $\gcd(a,b)$.

Here are my questions:

> **When does $\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))$ equal $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$?  What are the exceptions?**

I tried searching for examples and counterexamples via [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), it gave me these outputs for the following **GP** scripts:

```
for(x=1, 100, if(gcd(x,sigma(x^2))==gcd(x^2,sigma(x^2)),print(x)))
```

> All positive integers from $1$ to $100$ (except for the integer $99$) satisfy $\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$.

```
for(x=1, 1000, if(gcd(x,sigma(x^2))<>gcd(x^2,sigma(x^2)),print(x)))
```

> The following integers in the range $1 \leq m \leq 1000$ **DO NOT** satisfy $\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$.
>   $$99 = {3^2}\cdot{11}$$
>   $$154 = 2\cdot 7\cdot 11$$
>   $$198 = 2\cdot{3^2}\cdot{11}$$
>   $$273 = 3\cdot 7\cdot 13$$
>   $$322 = 2\cdot 7\cdot 23$$
>   $$396 = {2^2}\cdot{3^2}\cdot{11}$$
>   $$399 = 3\cdot 7\cdot 19$$
>   $$462 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 11$$
>   $$469 = 7\cdot 67$$
>   $$495 = {3^2}\cdot 5\cdot 11$$
>   $$518 = 2\cdot 7\cdot 37$$
>   $$546 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 13$$
>   $$553 = 7\cdot 79$$
>   $$620 = {2^2}\cdot 5\cdot 31$$
>   $$651 = 3\cdot 7\cdot 31$$
>   $$693 = {3^2}\cdot 7\cdot 11$$
>   $$741 = 3\cdot 13\cdot 19$$
>   $$742 = 2\cdot 7\cdot 53$$
>   $$770 = 2\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11$$
>   $$777 = 3\cdot 7\cdot 37$$
>   $$792 = {2^3}\cdot{3^2}\cdot 11$$
>   $$798 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 19$$
>   $$903 = 3\cdot 7\cdot 43$$
>   $$938 = 2\cdot 7\cdot 67$$
>   $$966 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 23$$
>   $$990 = 2\cdot{3^2}\cdot 5\cdot 11$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I know that primes $m_1 := p$ and prime powers $m_2 := q^k$ satisfy the equation, since then we have
$$\gcd(m_1, \sigma({m_1}^2)) = \gcd(p, \sigma(p^2)) = 1 = \gcd(p^2, \sigma(p^2)) = \gcd({m_1}^2, \sigma({m_1}^2)),$$
and
$$\gcd(m_2, \sigma({m_2}^2)) = \gcd(q^k, \sigma(q^{2k})) = 1 = \gcd(q^{2k}, \sigma(q^{2k})) = \gcd({m_2}^2, \sigma({m_2}^2)).$$

This shows that there are infinitely many solutions to the equation
$$\gcd(m, \sigma(m^2)) = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2)).$$

**Follow-Up Questions**

> What can be said about solutions to $\gcd(m, \sigma(m^2)) = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))$ for which the number of *distinct prime factors* $\omega(m)$ satisfies
>
> **(a)** $\omega(m)=2?$
>
> **(b)** $\omega(m)=3?$

Comment: For $(a)$ we could consider first integers $m=pq$, for distinct primes $p$ and $q$. The exceptions are $(p,q)=(7,67),(7,79),\ldots$. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988355/on-the-quantity-sigma-fracn2-sigman2dn2-when-q-n2-is-an-odd) seems related.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @DietrichBurde.  I did notice that too.  I do wonder why *most* exceptions in the range $[1, 1000]$ appear to be divisible by $7$.  I have not yet checked, but I will try to extend my search further.

Comment: This question is actually related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131818).

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Are you content with a calculation with a large search-limit, lets say, $\ m=10^8\ $ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes I would be interested to know whether *most* exceptions to the equation in *that range* **are divisible by** $7$.

Comment: @Peter I would also be interested to learn about answers to my last two questions, even if only just for **(a)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PARI/GP-routines efficiently determine the numbers of solutions and the ratio of numbers divisible by $\ 7\ $. You can easily adjust the range.

Exactly two prime factors

```
? q=0;r=0;for(m=1,10^7,if(omega(m)==2,if(gcd(m,sigma(m^2))<>gcd(m^2,sigma(m^2)),if(Mod(m,7)==0,q=q+1);if(Mod(m,7)<>0,r=r+1))));print(q,"  ",r,"   ",q+r,"   ",q/(q+r)*1.0)
5301  1216   6517   0.81341107871720116618075801749271137026
?
```

Over 80% of the exceptions are divisible by $\ 7\ $.

Exactly three prime factors

```
? q=0;r=0;for(m=1,10^7,if(omega(m)==3,if(gcd(m,sigma(m^2))<>gcd(m^2,sigma(m^2)),if(Mod(m,7)==0,q=q+1);if(Mod(m,7)<>0,r=r+1))));print(q,"  ",r,"   ",q+r,"   ",q/(q+r)*1.0)
77535  103019   180554   0.42942831507471448984791253586184742515
?
```

Here, the situation is quite different. Only about 43% of the exceptions are divisible by $\ 7\ $.